# FIRFacebookAuthProvider Internal Error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am working on app(swift 2.0) Facebook Auth with Firebase. Implemented each and every step carefully (doccumentation+working demo) My app successfully login to connected Facebook app on call of FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString) an exception is thrown 
detail exception and code attached with post
[image]

[image]

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/2WEwOu0h_u0

Comment: yes i posted the same . I have asked Facebook developer about this problem they said its firebase problem contact them.  so i posted it on google group too

Comment: Make sure the app_id in the Facebook access token (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling) is the same as the one you configured in Firebase Console (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login#before_you_begin, step 5).